# ¿Cómo hallar la longitud de un archivo en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

```
files <- dir(path = ".")
scan_file <- vapply(files, FUN = function(x) scan(x, what = "list"),
                    FUN.VALUE = "")
```

Tengo unos 5000 archivos que se leen con las dos funciones de arriba. En principio, todos los archivos se guardan en scan_file correctamente. Cada archivo contiene una secuencia de nucleótidos, de la cual debo hallar su longitud.
He intentado hacerlo con un bucle for:

```
for (file in scan_file){
  len <- length(file[[1]])
  cat(len)
  return(len)
}
```

Pero R me devuelve que la longitud es 1. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

También lo he intentado hacer con un `lapply`, con un resultado similar.

Fragmento de scan_file:

```
$`45792NJBAK082`
[1] "CAGCGCGTGCTTGACTAGTTATTTTACACTTGAGGCCGTGCCGTGACAGCCTACTGGTTATTATTGGAAGGGACAAGCGAGATCAGGCGCAGCCTGGTGTCTAGGTTAGAGTTCCAGCGAGGGAGACGCGACGCGGACCAGACCCTCGACAGGTCTATGTAACCCAAAGTGTCCTAATCCTTCAGTTTTGAACATGAAGAAGGTCCTTGCTTACAGGGTCGTAGAAAGGTTGCTTGGCCACGAATACT"

$`48927HSKA`
[1] "TGTGCCAAACACAAAGCGCGCGCGGTAGCTAGTCTGTATCCCGAACAAGCGCGAGACGATAACGAGGCCTGTGTAGCACCACATTGTCGCGT"

$`12NNUANLSO21`
[1] "CCGTCCCGCCACCATACCAGTCTCTCGTTCATACTCACTTCCCCTGAGATTTTTGAATTTTTAGTAAGTTTTATCACAAATACAGTCAGCATTACCGTTAGTTTTTGAGGAGGGCAGGACAACGGTATTACAGGGGACAAGAGGCCTTCCCACATGATCTACTGACCGCTCAGCTAGCTTGCATTAACTACCGTAAAAGAGGCCGGCGAAGCCCGGGCGTTGGGCAACAAGTCTAAGACCGCTCAAACGGCTTACTTAGGAGCTGGGGTGTCCTAGTGGGAGTCTTGAGAAGGGGCGGCAATCTCATGGGTATACGGCTCTAAAACTCTCTTTCGGGGCAGTGGAGGGACAAGGCACAAACCTGTAGTGACCTTTTATACACACATAAGGCGTCTCCGCATACTTTCAGGCCTTGCAACGGTAGGCTTTCATAGGTG"
```

Comment: Hola Kali, podrias poner un ejemplo de como sería tu objeto `scan_file`? A lo mejor está mal el `file[[1]]` pero no puedo imaginarme como es el objeto. A lo mejor queres usar la función `nchar` en vez de `length` Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! nchar sí que funciona, usándolo dentro de un sapply. De todas formas, voy a editar la pregunta para mostrar scan_file.

Answer (score 0):

El comentario de P. Paccioretti, es sin duda la respuesta adecuada a tu pregunta. Sin embargo otra forma de atacar el problema es usar `file.info()`, que es efectivamente la forma para obtener la longitud de un archivo. Pero esto, te aclaro, puede que no sea necesariamente lo que buscas:

```
file.info('archivo.txt')$size
```

Puedes también construir un `data.frame` con la lista de los archivos y sus respectivos tamaños:

```
files <- data.frame(name=dir(path = ".") , stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
files$size <- sapply(files$name, FUN=function(x) {file.info(x)$size})
head(files)

                        name   size
1            _bookdown_files      0
2                  _main.Rmd  18411
3        00001.Printfile.pdf  29984
4        00002.Printfile.pdf  29984
5 Analisis.Proyecto.III.docx 154324
6               Anexo_II.PDF 253954
```

Por lo que entiendo, tienes un conjunto de archivos con una única fila o cadena de texto y quieres saber la longitud de la misma. Bien, la solución que te comenté no lee el archivo, usa las rutinas del sistema para obtener la longitud de cada archivo, y la longitud del mismo no es mas que la cantidad total de bytes. No necesariamente la cantidad de bytes será la cantidad de caracteres de cada cadena, eso dependerá si los archivos se salvan con algún tipo de salto de línea, el cual habrá que descontar al número obtenido, por ejemplo en Windows los archivos de texto suelen salvarse con los caracteres 13 y 10 para indicar el fin de una línea, por lo que habría que restar 2 al numero retornado por `file.info()`, en Unix en cambio se usa solo uno de los caracteres mencionados y habrá que restar 1. Esta solución tiene la ventaja que no tiene que leer cada archivo, por lo que eventualmente puede que sea más performante.